# Navigate to Newly Record created record using Flow in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, screen-flow, navigationmixin.navigate

I am creating records using Lead from screen flow after creating i want user to navigate to the newly created Record i am using Navigation Mix in and trying to redirect the record .

Below is My LWC code

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

//1. Import Navigation Mixin named import
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

//2. Import encodeDefaultFieldValues named import
import { encodeDefaultFieldValues } from 'lightning/pageReferenceUtils';

export default class ExploreNewRecordNacWithDefaults extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
        //3. Invoke encodeDefaultFieldValues and pass the object
        @api recordId;
    handleNavigation() {
 
                
                //5. Invoke navigate by passing the config object
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId:  this.recordId,
                objectApiName: 'Lead',
                actionName: 'view'
            },
        
        });
    }
}




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="recordId" type="String" label="Current Lead Id" 
                        description="Id of the current record"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>[![Variables ][1]][1]
```

Below is MY Screen Flow and Elements . I am getting the error :

Error Occurred: Action failed: c:navigate$controller$invoke [Invalid destination type value: "00q5i000005grl3eao". Supported values: object, record, app, url, tab, knowledge, namedpage, relatedlist]

Can we use variable and store it an action element and get the record .

[image: Record Id Mapping in Action Item]

[image: Screen Element]

Comment: Can you share more info around how you map these inputs from flows to the navigation mixin variables

Comment: Hi @MohithShrivastava I have added the Xml file and the variables i am using to store the record ID

Comment: Consider using (or be inspired by) something like the unofficialsf.com [Navigate Everywhere](https://unofficialsf.com/navigate-everywhere-flow-action/) flow action.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the type parameter is not correct. Change `type: 'standard__objectPage',` to `type: 'standard__recordPage',` to *Navigate to View Lead Record Page*.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve forwarding to a specific record page from within a Flow by using LWC you can simply make use of Web API standards, in this case, functions of the [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) and [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) interfaces:

- use [location.origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/origin) to get the origin of the represented URL
- use [Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) to load a specific target URL

Within your LWC, you can assemble these functions as follows and just enrich the URL with the respective record id passed to the component from your Flow:

```
import { api, LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class OpenRecordPageFlowAction extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
  @api target = '_blank';

  connectedCallback() {
    const completeURL = `${window.location.origin}/${this.recordId}`;
    window.open(completeURL, this.target);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, since we cannot use an LWC as headless actions in Flows at this point, unlike Aura Components, and a screen is therefore still necessary, you can add a spinner in the template of your component as a loading indicator to achieve a visually appealing display for the user.

```
<template>
  <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="medium"></lightning-spinner>
</template>
```

If you want to forward to a previously created Account for example, configuring the LWC could look like:

[image]

I also published a step-by-step guide for this as a Medium post:
[How to open a Record Page from Salesforce Flow using LWC](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-open-a-record-page-from-salesforce-flow-using-lwc-a8a94bc0c9ba)

The full source code of the LWC including JEST unit tests and JSDoc comments is available on GitHub here: https://github.com/svierk/awesome-lwc-collection/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/openRecordPageFlowAction